# Proper use of on Sunday

Tags: adverbs

In my grammar book I read the following example sentence

> He goes on Sunday to church, and sits among his boys.

I think the above sentence is wrong because adverb phrase of place(to church) should be placed before adverb phrase of time(on Sunday)

Also I think it should be Sundays instead of Sunday

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that *He goes to church on Sunday* is the more common way to phrase this sentence; however, *He goes on Sunday to church* is not incorrect.

Changing the order changes the emphasis, so moving the indication of time draws attention to it. This is particularly useful in making parallel constructions:

> He goes on Sunday to church, and on Monday through Saturday to drink at the pub with greater fervor.

You might also adjust word order to group or to separate words to avoid ambiguity.

> In his religious studies class, on Easter Monday, he has a quiz on Good Friday in the Orthodox tradition.

Either *Sunday* or *Sundays* can reflect a habitual practice. *On Sunday* is more ambiguous, and could refer to a specific Sunday depending on context, whereas *on Sundays* invariably refers to multiple Sundays.

Answer (score 0):

> He goes to Church on Sunday...

Using "... on Sundays..." is also acceptable.

You can also say, with a change of emphasis "On Sunday, he goes to church..." or "He goes to church and sits with his boys on Sunday".

Comment: But is the sentence I posted earlier wrong?

Comment: No, it's a little poetic rather than pedestrian, but not wrong.